# How to set up columns in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

In this code I want to align columns of `Riscontri Trovati`.

This code is based on a CSV file of pokemon.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
        
sg.theme("BlueMono")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\riccardo\OneDrive\Desktop\pokemon.csv')
        
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Questa è una prova di ricerca\nInserisci i parametri che preferisci')],
    [sg.Text('Name'), sg.Input(key='Name')],
    [sg.Text('Type 1'), sg.Input(key='Type 1')],
    [sg.Text('Type 2'), sg.Input(key='Type 2')],
    [sg.Text('Total'), sg.Input(key='Total')],
    [sg.Text('Generation'), sg.Input(key='Generation')],
    [sg.Button('Search'), sg.Button('Close')]
 ]


window = sg.Window('Database sui pokemon', layout).Finalize()
        
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Close':
        break
        if event == 'Search':
            df_query = 'df.loc['
            for key,value in values.items():
                if value != '':
                    if value.isnumeric():
                        df_query += f'''(df['{key}'] == {value})&'''
                    else:
                        df_query += f'''(df['{key}'] == '{value}')&'''
            df_query = df_query[:-1] + ']'
            sg.popup_scrolled('Riscontri trovati', eval(df_query), size=(100,40))
   window.close()
```

And the result is:
[image]

Comment: Reduce your code to only `import PySimplGUI as sg`,  static value of `value`, `sg.popup_scrolled('Riscontri trovati', value, size=(100,40))`, then tell us about the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use monospace font for alignment if your csv file already aligned. If not, do some reformatting your data before you send them to `sg.popup_scrolled`.

```py
sg.popup_scrolled('Riscontri trovati', eval(df_query), size=(100,40), font=('Courier New`, 11))
```